# Does there exist a library of relational data models that represent common file formats?

Tags: data-modeling

Say I want to store JPEG/JFIF images in a relational database. The raw JPEG data might go in a BLOB column, and the EXIF metadata might require a few tables to represent all the different multiplicities of tags. But as the JPEG/JFIF format is fairly fixed and well-defined, I'm wondering if this has already been done.

The general question is whether anyone has published any such data models for well-known file formats..

Answer (score 0):

There exists several open source projects that provide image galleries and store their information in relational databases.

It might be a good idea for you to go over to those projects and read a little bit through their wiki pages to get an idea on how they model their image gallery.

Design3Edge has a nice overview over some open source project ([link](http://www.design3edge.com/2010/08/26/best-free-and-open-source-php-image-galleries/))